# Copying an existing Magento 1.7.2 site to run in localhost - Xampp

Tags: php, database, apache, magento-1.7

I'm trying to clone my Magento live store (version 1.7.2) on XAMPP Version 1.8.1 on Windows 10 because I need a dev/test env to upgrade to Magento 2.

I followed this instructions:

https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Installing+Magento+1.x+on+Windows+with+XAMPP+and+WAMP

Also these:

https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Reinstalling+Magento+Without+Re-uploading+the+Files

But when I run localhost/alimentarium2016/install I get these error:

```
"There has been an error processing your request
dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract
Trace:
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\Abstract.php(134): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->setConnection(false)
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(EM_Themeframework_Model_Resource_Page))
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('themeframework_...', Object(EM_Themeframework_Model_Resource_Page))
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\Mage.php(490): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('themeframework/...', Object(EM_Themeframework_Model_Resource_Page))
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('themeframework/...', Object(EM_Themeframework_Model_Resource_Page))
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\local\EM\Themeframework\Model\Layout\Update.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\local\EM\Themeframework\Model\Layout\Update.php(48): EM_Themeframework_Model_Layout_Update->_getPages('install_wizard')
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout\Update.php(224): EM_Themeframework_Model_Layout_Update->merge('install_wizard')
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(306): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->load()
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(259): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayoutUpdates()
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Install\controllers\WizardController.php(70): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout('install_wizard')
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Install\controllers\WizardController.php(113): Mage_Install_WizardController->_prepareLayout()
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(419): Mage_Install_WizardController->beginAction()
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('begin')
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
C:\xampp\htdocs\alimentarium2016\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
{main}"
```

I have tried several things, including i.e. erasing var/cache and var/session, and giving all permissions to the folder in which I need to reinstall Magento, but it does not work.

Could anyone help, please?

Thanks in advance. All the best!

Comment: ¡Solved! Instead of re-installing I just cloned the site copying all files from system backup and changing local.xmla fter creating Db in Phpmyadmin. Tx anyway